# create files.tar in debian PharData with PHP?

Tags: php, apache, zip, debian, tar

```
define('__ROOT__', dirname(__FILE__));

$phar = new PharData('proyecto.tar');
$phar->buildFromIterator(
    new ArrayIterator(
     array(
        'fichero/text.txt' => __ROOT__ . '/text.txt',
     )));
```

Don't create files.tar in Debian but in windows works perfectly(with XAMPP),
It is an issue of permit folders or Apache server configuration?

Answer (score -1):

sorry, i'm noob in SO of Unix. 
The problem was permissions in the directory.
I solved the conflict with chmod 777 nameCarpeta.